# Passing Github context to Javascript Action

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Is there a way to pass Github context to Javascript action from within the action iself?

For example, if using `composite` action I can do something like:

```yaml
...
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Do something with context
      shell: bash
      run: run.sh ${{ github.token }}
...
```

Where then in my `run.sh` I can use the token for API access.

However with Javascript actions I can't seem to find a way how to pass those variables:

```
...
runs:
  using: 'node12'
  main: 'index.js'
```

If I need the token, I will have to force user to pass it via `env` or `with` when using my action.

Is this is a limitation of the schema or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try using the [actions toolkit packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action?learn=create_actions#adding-actions-toolkit-packages) in your action implementation? They seem to offer access to GitHub Actions contexts for Javascript actions.

Comment: Yes, I use them for most of the stuff - `@actions/github` exposes the context but it's missing token.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```yaml
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Do something with context
      shell: bash
      run: node ${{ github.action_path }}/index.js ${{ github.token }}
```

Would like to know if it's possible to use the Javascript approach directly without this workaround.